# Probability of guessing correct pair with 2 dice

Tags: probability

We have an office discussion going.

What is the probability of correctly guessing a pair of 6 sided dice? Meaning 3-2 and 2-3 count as the same pair.

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on your guess.  $(2,3)$ is $\frac 2{36}$.  $(1,1)$ is $\frac 1{36}$.  (there are two ways to get $(2,3)$, as you point out, but only one way to get $(1,1)$).

Comment: It depends on how you guess.   What is the probability that you pick, the ordered pair $(x,y)$ for any $1\leq x\leq y\leq 6$.  Do you: write all pairs on pieces of paper and draw from a hat?  Do you roll your own pair of dice?  Do you use your mother's cousin's next-door-neighbour's daughter's favourite pet's birthdate?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a pair of fair 6 sided dice the probability of every $6 \cdot 6 =36$ distinct results are equal. When you do not take order into account it depends on your guess. Guessing (1,1),(2,2),...,(6,6) will all have a $\frac{1}{36}$ probability of being correct. Since only one of the 36 outcomes corresponds to the guess. If you guess distinct numbers your probability will be $\frac{2}{36}=\frac{1}{18}$ since for distinct numbers there are two combinations out of 36 outcomes that are considered correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1}{36}$ if you are picking pairs, like $(2,2)$.
$\dfrac{1}{18}$ if you are picking numbers like $2$ or $3$ without the order of appearance mattering.